# Why did Hawkeye have an ankle monitor in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, hawkeye

At the very beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*, it looked like Hawkeye was wearing a leg tag, the sort you wear if you've been released from prison for home imprisonment.

Was Hawkeye in trouble or did I miss-see something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

He has this from taking a plea deal at the end of *Captain America: Civil War* alongside Ant-Man for siding with Cap and breaking the Sokovia Accords.

> **Bruce Banner:** We need all hands on deck. Where's Clint?
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** After the whole Accords situation, he and Scott took a deal. It was too tough on their families, they're on house arrest.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Woo goes into detail about why this happened in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* when talking to Cassie... and he is really good at that.

> **Cassie:** Why can't you just leave my daddy alone?
>
> **Woo:** Oh, Cassie. This must all seem like a bunch of confusing grown-up stuff to you, huh? Well, think of it this way: Your school has rules, right? Like...You can't draw on the walls. Well, your Daddy went to Germany and drew on the walls with Captain America. And that was a violation of Article 16, Paragraph 3 of the Sokovia Accords. Now as a part of his joint plea deal with Homeland Security and the German government, he's allowed to return to the U.S., provided he serve two years under house arrest, followed by three years of probation. and avoid any unauthorized activities, technology, or contact with any former associates, who were or currently are, in violation of said Accords, or any related statutes. Okay sweetie?
>
> <sub>*Ant-Man and the Wasp*</sub>

And to be super clear here is Clint’s ankle monitor we see at the start of *Endgame* compared to Scott's we see in *Ant-Man and the Wasp*.

[image: Close up of Clint and his daughter’s feet together as he stands behind her adjusting her posture for archery. He is wearing the ankle monitor] [image: Close up of Scott's ankle monitor with someone inserting a device into it to release it from him as his house arrest is up]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: I love Woo's acting here... trying to kidify his explanation, but still getting all of the nitty-gritty details in there.

Comment: Woo scene currently here : https://youtu.be/NtUMnzvAWVM

Comment: Also note that when his family gets dusted, he goes rogue (or Ronin to be precise).  I assume the Avengers are still able to track him using this anklet, as they find him pretty easily in Japan later on.  (I can only assume the reason he wasn't brought in by the authorities before that is that everyone else who cared was also dusted?)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman They find him by tracking his movements after he hits places. Rhodey has been tracking him on Nat's orders. At the check in stage he reports he's in Mexico and Nat asks him to find out where he's going next. That wouldn't be necessary if he had the ankle monitor on still. We also see his ankles in Tokyo and I don't spot the monitor.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: It would sort of defeat the point/make no sense if he was wearing an anklet tracking his movements while he was "rogue" and traveling the world killing random criminals...

Comment: Still seemed a bit too easy to find him.  Japan's a big place - even if you knew as specifically as "Tokyo", it'd take some work to track down a guy who's actively trying not to be found in a large city like that.  (Of course, since it's the FBI who's keeping tabs, they're not technically allowed to operate outside of US soil, so maybe that's why he was hiding out in Mexico and Japan, etc.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's Rhodey who is keeping tabs and has been doing so for quite a while. At some point you start closing in and working out the patterns. Rhodey and the Avengers aren't part of the FBI. And remember Ronin is after large scale crime units, that narrows the search locations down a lot... even more so with the more he kills.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, both Scott Lang and Clint Barton are wearing [ankle monitors](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ankle_Monitor) as a result of getting caught in the airport brawl during *Avengers: Civil War*.

> Due to the violation of the Sokovia Accords, several Avengers were arrested and imprisoned inside the Raft. Clint Barton and Scott Lang decided to cut a deal with a government so they could return to their families. The authorities equipped both of them with monitors and appointed the FBI to keep track of them.